# Why this strange thing happening to my DOM element?

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I basically started learning react-redux and I am in the middle of creating some simple store app. I would introduce my problem in a few bullet points.

I have got a basic store with some states and the Navbar where I have the Cart button.
After the click of the cart button, I want to open the cart list and rotate the Cart icon for 90deg.
I want to put everything in the one function and attach it to onClick()
my code looks like that: https://codepen.io/szygendaborys/pen/wZYZor?editors=0010

The main problem is that all works if I cancel the statement after else. That one:

```
else {
style = 'none';
cartArrow.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)'
}
```

If I put back that statement, I receive an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null connected to

```
cartArrow.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)'
```

Can anyone help me and explain why the if statement works and else does not?

Comment: Please include the relevant code here on Stack Overflow, not only on an external site. There is no `if` statement in the code I can see here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cartArrow` element likely hasn't rendered at the point of your DOM query (`getElementById`), which is an anti-pattern in React to begin with. Make use of [`refs`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) instead.

```
<i
  ref={(ref) => this.cartArrow = ref}
  id='cartArrow'
  className="fas fa-angle-right"
></i>
```

```
this.cartArrow.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)'
```